# Getting back to first image when removing mouse-over

Tags: jquery, image, thumbnails

I have this script which allows a list of thumbs to rotate when you hover your mouse over the image (which is very cool btw!)

You can check the code over here and play around with it:

http://jsfiddle.net/vfpK4/36/

I actually want the images to get back to the **first image** when I move the mouse away, however I am really no so familiar with jQuery, is there anyone who can adjust the code a bit? (probably very easy, but still too hard for me)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this: **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/vfpK4/37/)**.

You can just set a variable to store the original image source, then feed it back to the image on mouseout.

jQuery:

```
var intervalId;
var first = $('img').attr('src'); 
$('img').hover(function() {
    var $img = $(this),
        imageList = $img.attr('class').split('@');
    // start the rotation
    intervalId = window.setInterval(function() {
        // cycle array
        imageList.unshift(imageList.pop());
        $img.attr('src', imageList[0]);
    }, 500);
}, function() {
    // stop the cycle
    intervalId = window.clearInterval(intervalId);
    $('img').attr('src', first);
});
```

Comment: j08691, can this script be adjusted to: if mouse hovers over a div with class="list-item", then the image with class="thumb" should rotate?

Comment: Wow, you are very close! Actually I have multiple instances of list items, of which each has its own unique images... so actually when removing the mouse, they should return to their own first image... example html code: http://jsfiddle.net/vfpK4/56/